# What are these tags related to on the Newest Questions page?

Tags: support, tags, question-lists, related-tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions

On the right, there is a widget that lists "Related Tags" (left − SO April 2013, right − MSE May 2014):

> [image] [image]

What are they related to? There isn't even a question selected. Are they related to the whole displayed list?

This can be seen on every SE site.

Comment: Life, the Universe, and Everything?

Comment: Well, I am a C# programmer mostly, so that makes sense.

Comment: +1 It's a valuable feature. Just a few words **about** it wouldn't harm.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, "Related" is wrong in case you view the whole list.

I'll start from the actual use of that "widget": when you're viewing a specific tag page e.g. [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) the Related Tags lists tags having most questions tagged with both the tag you're viewing and other tag. So for example, if the list for C# tag contains this:

> [image]

It means there are 12,782 questions tagged both [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) so Related Tags are "tags that frequently appear together".

Now when you don't view any tag (i.e. main questions list) it just show the top tags, sorted by amount of questions, same order as in the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), popular tab.

So changing to "Top Tags" or "Popular Tags" when not viewing a specific tag is a reasonable request.

Comment: +1 What are your observations about tags related to tags?

Comment: Well, they are *technically* related... They're related to everything.

Comment: @Wolf if two tags are both used frequently together then yes, they are somewhat related. When thinking about it, I can't find a better word so guess I'll edit the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, obviously: I just tried `c#` and got a related `.net` (103639) and after that I tried  `.net` and got a related `c#` (103639)

Comment: @Wolf yep it's symmetric. :)

Comment: I have the feeling that your first sentence (*Actually, "Related" is wrong in case you view the whole list.*) needs a rework.

Comment: @wolf why is that?

Answer (score -1):

[Realted to the whole list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/?pagesize=1). Not only displayed.

Comment: I guess this list should be called something else then. Like "Most Popular Tags" or "Most Used Tags".

Comment: @user1306322, but this list [can be more specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?pagesize=1) when you select additional param.

Comment: If you do so, it becomes a whole other page, and then the context appears in which "Related" is valid